# IIS Masked Header issue

Tags: iis, hosting, web-hosting

I have an IIS server on which am trying to run two copies of the same website. I have only one public IP for this server.

So, to differentiate which site to open, I created two masked host names like

```
site1.mysite.com
site2.mysite.com
```

Both these masks hit the same public IP on the same Port 80.

Now, in the bindings, I set the two websites to be mapped to these masked site host names.
And when I hit the sites, I get 404.

if I dont use a mask, by doing a http://localhost - am able to open the site correctly.

Any thoughts on what could be wrong ?

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html If you run some diagnostics, the cause should be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please check whether the request has been logged in IIS. If the request is not logged, then there must be something wrong with your IIS binding or DNS entry.

So the problem is how did you register the masked host name?

1.Please ensure the website can be accessed from your public IP address. localhost always mapped to 127.0.0.1. So it doesn't represent public ip can be accessed. If it is not accessiable from public IP. Please ensure your server is mapeed to DMZ.

2.Now that you are trying to access website from public IP, please ensure you have purchased the domain name and map it to your public domain.  If you are registering the site in hosts file, please try nslookup and check whether it is mapping to the right place.

3.Please try to stop other sites and only start specific testing site. Then set your binding with host name and IP address.

Comment: the masked host name is a subdomain of my domain

let us say i have a domain like www.mywebsite.com
I created two subdomains 

www.site1.mywebsite.com
www.site2.mywebsite.com

and in my IIS, I setup 
site1.mywebsite.com as host for one site
site2.mywebsite.com as host for another site.

the two websites run from different folders on my IIS.

So my expectation was, when i hit site1.mywebsite.com the IIS should look at the hostname and launch the page from folder 1

and if i hit site2.mywebsite.com the IIS should look at the hostname and launch the page from folder 2.

Comment: @NRB IIS can share IP and port as long as you set different host name for your websites. Could you see that 404 error in your IIS log? What is its subs-status code?

Comment: 2020-07-03 07:05:08 172.31.44.152 GET / - 80 - 85.171.37.245 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/83.0.4103.116+Safari/537.36 http://domain.xyx.co.uk/ 200 0 0 102


The domain name is actually a masked forwarding name

This is the entry I see... I have changed the IP and the domain from the logs when I pasted here.. but this is the only entry I see from IIS logs when I hit the site..

I must admit unfamiliarity in reading the logs

Comment: This request is returning 200 instead of 404 error. So the request must be sent to somewhere else. Could you access our website from IP and have you pointed your domain to the valid IP address?  Please check this with nslookup.

Comment: I dont know how I solved it. But earlier the domain name I used for binding was using IP masking.
Subsequently, I used a subdomain and then also used an A record to map to the IP. It solved this problem. But I admit am not clear or sure about it.